# edge length in networkx

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to adjust the length of edge between two nodes by following code. But apparently it didn't work. Could anyone guide me where I am making mistake: Please note that I already look at this thread ([How to specify edge length in Networkx for calculating shortest distance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33863550/how-to-specify-edge-length-in-networkx-for-calculating-shortest-distance))  but didn't solve my issue

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1,2])
G.add_edge(1,2, length = 10)  # I also replaced length with len but no luck
nx.draw(G,with_labels=True)
plt.show() # display
```

Comment: In networkx you can attach any attributes you want to the edge. Did you get an exception when adding `length` attribute or what?

Comment: You say "**But apparently it didn't work**" How did you understand that?

Answer (score 6):

How about this:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1,2])
G.add_edge(1,2, length = 10)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos)
plt.show()
```

It will look like this:

[image]

You can also play around with `draw_networkx_edge_labels`'s parameters to print out just exactly what you want.

Comment: I would use `nx.spring_layout(G, weight='length')`, as the spring layout algorithm will try to position the nodes based on that edge attribute.

[Spring Layout reference](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html "Spring Layout")

Comment: This does not adjust the edge length!!  Even if you use length=0 you will get the same result. Only the label on the edge will change! You totally missed the point. Or did I?

Comment: @Apostolos Actually, there is no edge! <enter The Matrix meme here>. Since we do not specify the nodes' coordinates then any definition of an edge is meaningless. Nevertheless, since this is merely a plotting tool, it is good enough in my opinion.

Comment: @bergerg, 1) I see an **edge**; it's **very visible**! :)  2) The question asks about **edge length **  and 3) why then do you use **length=10**`?   Anyway, thes are rhetorical questions. Too many odd points. No need to answer. I don't really care ...

Comment: For spring layout in NetworkX, the edge lengths define the strength of attraction between nodes. So using a distance metric as the weight will lead to the opposite of what we want. Using `1/distance` may help, but I don't think it promises that the displayed edge lengths will be proportional to the data.

Answer (score 5):

Networkx does not have a layout function that infers node positions based on a given set of edge lengths.
However, [netgraph](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph), which is a python library for making better network visualisations, does implement the desired functionality in the geometric node layout. In the example below, I am using an edge list to represent the network, but netgraph also accepts networkx, igraph, and graph-tool Graph objects.

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from netgraph import Graph # pip install netgraph OR conda install -c conda-forge netgraph

# right triangle
edge_length = {
    (0, 1) : 0.3,
    (1, 2) : 0.4,
    (2, 0) : 0.5,
}
edges = list(edge_length.keys())

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
Graph(edges, edge_labels=edge_length, node_layout='geometric',
      node_layout_kwargs=dict(edge_length=edge_length), ax=ax)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

If you only want the node positions but you don't want to use netgraph for plotting, you can compute the node positions using the `get_geometric_layout` function:

```
from netgraph import get_geometric_layout

pos = get_geometric_layout(edges, edge_length)
```

###### Edit:

Thanks @DanielDarabos for the completely unnecessary but much appreciated bounty!

Answer (score -1):

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pygraphviz import *

# use PyGraphviz to create the initial graph with lengths
A = AGraph()
nlist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
A.add_nodes_from(nlist)
A.add_edge('a','b',len=1)
A.add_edge('a','c',len=3)
A.add_edge('b','c',len=8)

# convert to NetworkX Graph from a PyGraphviz graph
G = nx.nx_agraph.from_agraph(A)
pos = nx.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos)
plt.show()
```

The output image would look like:
[graph with predifined edge lengths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bq9M.png)