# Shortest Path in a NetworkX graph is not same as length of edge between shortest path nodes

Tags: python, networkx, shortest-path

I have a NetworkX Graph with two edges as following code:

```
import networkx as nx
GH = nx.Graph()
GH.add_edge(0, 1, len=3)
GH.add_edge(0, 2, len=7.5)
GH.add_edge(1,2,len=2)
```

I want to find the shortest path length between node 0 and node 1. I'm expecting it to be 3, but it's coming to be 1. The code used for this is:

```
nx.shortest_path_length(GH,0,1)
```

I understand that I'm setting an edge attribute 'len' in first snippet of code and hence it might not be changing the edge length. But is there a way we can achieve results as I am expecting it to be?

Comment: apparently `shortest_path_length` would find the number of edges among nodes i believe. Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33863550/how-to-specify-edge-length-in-networkx-for-calculating-shortest-distance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a weight attribute

```
nx.shortest_path_length(GH,0,2, weight='len')
```

gets intended results.